# Download pdf with Fax cover sheet Docusign?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Is there a way from code (c#) end to initiate **fax** request similar to sign documents electronically (or embedded signing) .

I refereed to the documentation **[over here](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Embedding%20Group/RequestRecipientFaxPDF.htm)** but not sure i understand what need to be done . can someone throw some light on this , i don't see any API methods to do such .

After request is made i need to download PDF version with fax cover , so i can fax them back .

Comment: Are you using the Docusign [REST Api](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/) or [SOAP Api](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-soap-sdk)?

Comment: I'm using rest API . Is there a way @CodingDawg .

Answer (score 2):

Rest API does not support the [RequestRecipientFaxPDF](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Embedding%20Group/RequestRecipientFaxPDF.htm) operation. It was supported in the legacy SOAP Api.

The other option is to generate a signing link for the [embedded recipient](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/) and use the [Print & Sign](https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-user-guide-signing-sign-on-paper-new) option to download the PDF with the Fax cover.